# I have cloned a .net core and angular project from gitlab and I installed the node module also. But when I run the project why I found cannot get/

Tags: angular, typescript, .net-core

[Console picture for the error][1]

The picture is showing the error for better understand.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UFrdx.jpg

Comment: are you sure serve app in port 56575 for example you must run this --> 
ng serve --port 56575

Comment: its related with one of the http calls , can u show me your network tab ? i think the resorce you want dose not exist.

Comment: the project run from the develop branch, but when I try to run it from other branch it shows cannot get/

Comment: @AnisurRahman maybe the other branches have code that is not working? Is it not sufficient that develop branch works? What is the difference between the branches? Is there a certain branch you need?

Comment: I run a branch in my office and work on it, after working I push the changes. But when I clone the project in my home the same branch is showing cannot get/